# App not responding after launching a new activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

The game starts from `MainActivity` class (that extends `Activity`) and then calls new `GamePanel` that extends `SurfaceView`, and there are many classes that update the game, so there is a class (`GameplayScene`) that checks the touch and check what happened to the game (if the user win or lose), so there is an update method that check if the player wins or lose and if the player win or lose then I want to start a new activity that have a button to restart the game,

The issue is: After starting the new activity (by using `Intent` from a class that does not extends anything) the app does not respond (but it displays the new activity correctly)

the class that starts the new activity from () :

```
public class GameplayScene implements Scene {   

public GameplayScene() {
....

@Override
public void recieveTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (!youWin && !gameOver && player.getRectangle().contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()))
                movingPlayer = true;
                forBegin = false;
            if (gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime >= 2000) {
                reset();
                gameOver = false;
            }
            if (youWin && System.currentTimeMillis() - winTime >= 2000) {
                reset();
                youWin = false;

            }
            if(!youWin && !gameOver && !movingPlayer) {
                if(!forBegin && System.currentTimeMillis() - fireTime >= 200) {
                    touchFire = true;
                    count = 1;
                    fireTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!youWin && !gameOver && movingPlayer)
                playerPoint.set((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            movingPlayer = false;
            touchFire = false;
            break;
    }
}


//@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    //Drawable d = getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.bgi);
    //d.setBounds(0, 0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    //d.draw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bgi, null, new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight()),new Paint());

    player.draw(canvas);
    obstacleManager.draw(canvas);

    if(gameOver) {
        Context contX = Constants.CONTEXT;
        Intent intent = new Intent(contX , result.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("toWR",0);
        contX.startActivity(intent);


    }
    if(youWin) {

        Context contX = Constants.CONTEXT;
        Intent intent = new Intent(contX , result.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("toWR",1);
        contX.startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

Android manifest :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".main_menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <SurfaceView android:name=".GamePanel"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".result"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

Comment: put a log in your new Activity's `onCreate(...)` and monitor logcat when you press the button. I suspect that you're launching too mant `result` activities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have some kind of `DrawingThread(...)` that is delegating the `draw(...)` to this `Scene`. If that is the case, then you're probably aiming for 60 updates per second... which means this intent will try to launch 60 times per second. That's probably what is causing your app to seem like it isn't responding.

Instead of launching an intent from in here, change the state of your game (or reuse the `gameOver` state) and interrupt your game loop (drawing thread). Then, start your activity *once* outside of the game loop, but before your thread finishes.